# Bind F1 to a user function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, callback

By default, Matlab binds F1 to the `doc` command. I'd like to change that binding to `doc2`, which is a function of mine. Unfortunately, the documentation is not very helpul with that matter.

Is there a simple way to achieve this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that, and MATLAB does not at all bind <kbd>F1</kbd> to the `doc` command.

By default, <kbd>F1</kbd> is bound to a few different things, depending on what desktop component you're using at the moment, and whether you have anything selected. In the MATLAB desktop, if nothing is selected, it will open up the Help Browser; but if something is selected, it will do Help on Selection instead, and if you're in the Genome Browser from Bioinformatics Toolbox, it will do something different again, specific to that tool.

You can modify those bindings in the MATLAB Preferences (Keyboard->Shortcuts); but you can only remap the bindings for existing actions, not create your own.

When the default action of opening up the Help Browser is carried out by a keyboard shortcut, it is not done by calling the `doc` command (that would be a bad idea, as the user may have modified or replaced the `doc` command to do something unrelated to help).